# Why doesn't "trap EXIT" work in background jobs in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a script that starts a bunch of jobs in the background and then waits until all of them run to completion.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

cleanup() {
    wait
    echo cleanup
}

do_work() {
    sleep 2
    echo done "$@"
}

run() {
    trap cleanup EXIT
    do_work 1 &
    # ... some code that may fail ...
    do_work 2 &
    # I can't just call cleanup() here because of possible early exit
}

# The script itself runs in the background too.
run&
```

To ensure that this script will wait for all its child processes, even if something goes wrong while spawning them, I use `trap cleanup EXIT` instead of just `cleanup` at the end.

But when I run this script in different shells, I get the following results:

```
$ for sh in zsh dash 'busybox ash' bash; do echo "$sh:"; $sh script.sh; sleep 3; echo; done
zsh:
done 1
done 2
cleanup

dash:
done 1
done 2
cleanup

busybox ash:
done 2
done 1
cleanup

bash:
done 2
done 1

$
```

In Bash the trap command seems to be completely ignored. What might be the reason for that? Any way to fix it?

`man bash-builtins` says something about signals ignored upon entry to the shell that cannot be trapped, but I have no idea how that applies to this situation...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call `exit` at the end of `run`:

```sh
run() {
    trap cleanup EXIT
    do_work 1 &
    # ... some code that may fail ...
    do_work 2 &
    # I can't just call cleanup() here because of possible early exit
    exit
}
```

Comment: *Just call exit at the end of run* Why? Do you have any explanation why it's required in bash but not in other shells?

Comment: @oguzismail believe OP did ask how to trigger cleanup here: 'Any way to fix it?'

Comment: Wow, that actually worked. I wouldn't even have thought about calling exit explicitly. Any idea on where I could read more on this? I was pretty sure that EXIT is guaranteed to be triggered when a script just ends.

Comment: @oguzismail no I'm sorry I don't have an explanation but the explicit `exit` was empirically tested to work on two versions of bash: `3.2.57(1)-release` and `4.3.48(1)-release`.

Comment: Okay. This might be a bug btw, consider reporting it. If you set a RETURN trap instead of EXIT, it works without explicit exit.

Comment: Agree with @oguzismail; I can't see anything in the documentation suggesting that there should be anything unique about about a subshell created in this manner.

Comment: Marking this as solved, it was indeed a bug: https://savannah.gnu.org/support/?109840